# Function to allow only alphabets and store its equivalent numbers

Tags: c

```
void keyfunction()
{
    int i=0,j=0,flag=1,ikey[15],keylength;
    char ch,chc,ckey[15];
    while(flag)
    {
        printf("Enter the length of key\n");
        scanf("%d",&keylength);
        printf("Enter the key\n");
        flag=0;
        for(j=0;j<keylength;j++)
        {
            scanf("%c",&ckey[j]);
        }
        j=0;
        for(j=0;j<keylength;j++)
        {
            chc=ckey[j];
            if(isalpha(chc))
            {
                continue;

            }
            else
            {
                printf("key should have only alphabets\n");
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while(1)
    {
        ch=ckey[i];
        if(isupper(ch))
        {
            ch=tolower(ch);
        }
        ikey[i]=ch-'a'+1;
        i++;
        if(keylength==i)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("key is accepted\n");
    while(i<keylength)
    {
        printf("%c",ckey[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

This function should ask a key length and accept the key only when it has alphabets and `ckey` array stores the characters of key entered. `ikey` array stores the corresponding int value of characters in `ckey` i.e if `ckey` has a,b,c,d then `ikey` stores 1,2,3,4.

Can anyone explain me where am I wrong?

Comment: Describe the problem you have:  a. What do you expect to see?  b. What *are* you seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
scanf("%c",&ckey[j]);
```

To

```
scanf(" %c",&ckey[j]);
```

While printing you are not increamenting index value

Change this

```
while(i<keylength)
{
    printf("%c",ckey[i]);
}
```

To

```
i=0;   // start index with zero
while(i<keylength)
{
    printf("%c",ckey[i]);
    i++;   //increment index
}
```

Comment: himanshu i am new for practical programming.In my college importance is only given to marks but i want to learn more can you suggest me pathway to get better in programming or any suggestions.i can really use some  suggestions

Comment: @mabhi95a10, if you are interested in coding you can start from basic program. There are some sites like http://www.sourcecodesworld.com/ , http://www.codeproject.com/kb/cpp . There you can download some projects and learn what that program is doing and how it has been coded. if you are getting any trouble you can ask question on stackoverflow. we all are here to help each other and solve our coding problem :)